# Allowing and restricting access to specific URL in Apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, web-server

I am new to apache. And I want to restrict access to this URL(https://testserver.com/admin.php) for public IP addresses. And I want to allow access to the same URL for specific IP addresses.
I am using debian 11 and apache version is 2.4

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read [the vendor documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html)** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681).

Answer (score 1):

I did it by myself by putting the following in the vhost file.

<Directory /var/www/html/admin.php>
Require ip XX.XX.XX.XX

Comment: Well done, for being new you found the best way to solve it.